# Django Cookiecutter using environment variables pattern in production

Tags: cookiecutter-django

I am trying to understand how to work with production .env files in a django cookie cutter generated project.

The documentation for this is here:

https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally-docker.html#configuring-the-environment

The project is generated and creates .local and .production folders for environment variables.

I am attempting to deploy to a docker droplet in digital ocean.

Is my understanding correct:

The .production folder is **NEVER** checked into source control and are only generated as examples of what to create on a production machine when I am ready to deploy?

So when I do deploy , as part of that process I need to do a pull/clone of the project on the docker droplet and then either

manually create the .production folder with the production environment variables folder structure?

OR

RUN merge_production_dotenvs_in_dotenv.py locally to create .env file that I copy onto production and the configure my production.yml to use that?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The production env files are NOT into source control, only the local ones are. At least that is the intend, production env files should not be in source control as they contain secrets.

However, they are added to the docker image by docker-compose when you run it. You may create a Docker machine using the [Digital Ocean driver](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/digital-ocean/), activate it from your terminal, and start the image you've built by running `docker-compose -f production.yml -d up`.

Answer (score -2):

Django cookiecutter does add `.envs/.production` and infact everything in `.envs/` folder into source control. You would know this by checking the `.gitignore` file. The `.gitignore` file does not contain `.envs` meaning the `.envs/` folder is checked into source control.

So when you want to deploy, you clone/pull the repository into your server and your `.production/` folder will be there too.

You can also run `merge_production_dotenvs_in_dotenv.py` to create `.env` file but the `.env` would not be checked into source control so you have to copy the file to your server. Then you can configure your docker-compose file to include `path/to/your/project/.env` as the `env_file` for any service that needs the environment variables in the file.

You can use **scp** to copy files from your local machine to your server easily like this:

```
scp /path/to/local/file username@domain-or-ipaddress:/path/to/destination
```

Comment: I have just created a fresh django cookie cutter project and this is at the bottom .of the file:
 .env
.envs/*
!.envs/.local/  which says it keeps everything except prod envs?

Comment: You're right Chris, the local .env files may be kept in source control but not the production ones. This answer is inaccurate.

Comment: I just checked again. My bad, I must have edited my own project's `.gitignore` file. Thanks for the clarification!